# Custom seekbar android progress not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar

my seekbar code

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/hand" />
```

my progress.xml code

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape
        android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:width="16dp"
            android:dashGap="8dp"
            android:dashWidth="2dp"
            android:color="#c5ccca" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <shape
        android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:width="16dp"
            android:dashGap="8dp"
            android:dashWidth="2dp"
            android:color="#58e9c5" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <shape
        android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:width="16dp"
            android:dashGap="8dp"
            android:dashWidth="2dp"
            android:color="#58e9c5" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I am getting this output
[no baseline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI0Mm.gif)

but I want this output where baseline is the below image on which thumb slides
[want this as baseline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf87P.png)

Why progress (base line) of seekbar is not visible, only thumb is visible? Thumb can be scrolled but cannot see the baseline on which it scrolls.

Comment: I think may be you have to set some minimum height for your seekbar.

Comment: Can you please add screenshot here